# Find default gateway ip address, rather than parsing proc filesystem

Tags: c, linux, default, routes

How should I obtain the ip address of default gateway ? Rather than read entries from /proc , is there any standalone API useable ?

Comment: You can do this with libiproute2

Comment: I would strongly advise just using `/proc`. It is the preferred method and the other methods tend to require privileged access.

Comment: In theory, there could be a number of symmetrically configured interfaces for increased capacity and/or redundancy.

Comment: /proc/net/route is one bet but much better is to use sample code from here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/howto-find-gateway-address-through-code-397078/

Answer (score 5):

you can use [libnl](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/) which is a library to communicate with the kernel via NETLINK sockets.

a simple example to get the default route would be (please add error checking and the needed headers)

```
   void cb_route (struct nl_object *cb, void *arg) {
        struct rtnl_route *route = (struct rtnl_route*) cb;
        /* do what you need to do with rtnl_route object 
         * e.g. copy it to arg, etc.
         */
        struct nl_addr *tmp_addr;
        tmp_addr = rtnl_route_get_gateway(route);
        len = nl_addr_get_len(tmp_addr);
        memcpy(arg, nl_addr_get_binary_addr(tmp_addr), len);
   }

   int get_route () {
        struct nl_handle *nlh;
        struct nl_cache *route_cache;
        struct rtnl_route *filter;
        struct nl_addr *dst;
        char *gw = malloc(16); //enough room for IPv6 if needed
        char n = '0';

        nlh = nl_handle_alloc();
        if (!nlh)
            return -1;

        nl_connect(nlh, NETLINK_ROUTE);
        route_cache = rtnl_route_alloc_cache();

        if (nl_cache_is_empty(route_cache))
             return 0;

        dst = nl_addr_build(AF_INET, &n, 0);
        filter = rtnl_route_alloc();
        rtnl_route_set_scope(filter, RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE);
        rtnl_route_set_family(filter, AF_INET);
        rtnl_route_set_table(filter, RT_TABLE_MAIN);
        rtnl_route_set_dst(filter, dst);

        nl_cache_foreach_filter(route_cache, (struct nl_object*) filter, cb_filter_route, gw);
        /* gw should now contain the binary representation of the default gw. use inet_ntop to convert it */

        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example, that would work with **libnl3**?  `nl_socket_alloc()` instead of `nl_handle_alloc()`. What is the analouge to `rtnl_route_get_gatewa`y in libnl3?

Answer (score 0):

A trick would be to use sockets api to attempt to connect to an unreachable ip. The response of "unreachable destination" would come from your default gateway.

Comment: Not necessarily. In the presence of multiple gateways, the default gateway might not even enter the picture.

Comment: Agreed, though i meant ensuring and using a destination network address which is only responded by a default gateway. Moreover, default gateway usage is the common case for a normal user accessing the Internet